# What will 10X Genomics want to test on the upcoming Axiom Space AX-2 mission?

Tags: microgravity, life, research, business

CNN's [Former NASA Astronaut Plans Private Trip Back to Space](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/05/25/tech/spacex-axiom-ax2-peggy-whitson-scn/index.html) begins

> Record-holding NASA astronaut [Peggy Whitson](https://edition.cnn.com/2017/04/23/politics/nasa-astronaut-peggy-whitson-trump/index.html)<sup>1</sup> has spent more time in outer space than almost any other human on the planet, but even in retirement she's desperate to go back. On Tuesday, the 61-year-old Whitson revealed that she will do just that — and this time, she's flying private.
>
> Axiom, a Houston-based company that focuses on arranging commercial flights to space, announced that Whitson will pilot a mission dubbed AX-2, which could be among the first privately funded civilian missions to space to launch from US soil.

and later says:

> Whitson, who nabbed the American record for time spent in space during her 22-year NASA career, said the AX-2 mission will likely be less onerous than the trips she's made to space on behalf of the US space agency. Still, Whitson said, she and Shoffner will be keeping busy: Shoffner plans to host livestreams from space to encourage math and science education. **And they'll be supporting research projects for a company called 10XGenomics, Shoffner said.**

**Question:** Are there any papers, press-releases or other information on what [10X Genomics](https://www.10xgenomics.com/) plans on testing during the upcoming [Axiom Space Mission 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_Mission_2) or AX-2 mission? The company focuses on technology to measure gene expression localized *within a single cell*, but I can't see how microgravity would play into that. Since this is research by a private company I'm guessing that the work should benefit their products and their use on Earth rather than doing basic science research exploring the biological effects of spaceflight, but I could be completely wrong about that.

---

<sup>1</sup>Jeanne Moos' video: interesting/humorous observations on several levels (e.g. discussing the drinking of processed urine with the former US president) "Better you than me!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link (https://www.cnbc.com/2021/05/25/axiom-space-ax-2-spaceflight-led-by-peggy-whitson-and-john-shoffner.html), and the others below, suggest that rather than doing medical-based research themselves, it appears to be more focused on "meta-research"; evaluating how research methods and techniques change in space:

> In addition to training for Ax-2, Whitson and Shoffner are working
> with California-based biotechnology company 10x Genomics to perform
> research in orbit on single-cell genomic methods.
>
> “Their products are used by all the top 100 research facilities around
> the world, researchers in orbit have been looking for the same
> capabilities,” Shoffner said of 10x Genomics.
>
> The company’s research will look to help answer questions such as how
> humans live in space long-term. Whitson noted that the the Ax-2
> mission’s shorter duration will get the research back to 10x Genomics
> faster.
>
> “Accessibility is one of the advantages of flying it with us, as it
> can get to orbit sooner and be tested sooner,” Whitson said.

From (https://www.axiomspace.com/press-release/ax2):

> In addition to their flight training, **they will learn how to translate
> terrestrial single-cell genomic methods to an orbital science process**
> in collaboration with Pleasanton, Calif.-based 10x Genomics, a global
> leader in developing products to master biology for advancing human
> health whose offerings are used by all of the top 100 global research
> institutions.

They do however have plans to use what they learn in other studies (https://cosmiclog.com/2021/05/25/record-setting-astronaut-will-lead-private-space-mission/):

> “The human body is made up of 40 trillion cells, each of which is
> changing all the time. 10x is focused on looking into single cells,
> which gives researchers more information about the human body than we
> had before,” the company explained in an emailed statement.
>
> 10x Genomics says it’s looking for ways to apply single-cell genomics
> to immunology, neuroscience and the study of cancer.
>
> “While we are still in the early stages of what we could do in space,
> there are projects that could help us understand how cells react in
> space vs. Earth that could lead to new discoveries,” the company said.
> **“Early studies would probably be looking at RNA expression for areas
> like osteoporosis to see how bone density is affected by gravity.”**

Comment: "will look to help answer questions such as how humans live in space long-term." lol. Real cutting edge, that.

Comment: Sounds like their goal is to advertise their product and their company rather than do actual research.

Comment: From looking at a couple of papers (e.g. https://www.mdpi.com/1422-0067/20/9/2316/pdf), 10x Genomics equipment and methods are already used in space-related experiments, so it's not completely performative, but it would be nice if the results were published, rather than just improving a product.

Comment: @user2705196 that may become the new norm for "privately funded civilian missions".